# Are BouncyCastle's AES engines hardware accelerated?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, aes-ni

I wonder if anyone knows if BouncyCastle's [AES engines](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines) support hardware acceleration, e.g., make use of AES-NI. My understanding is that some "native code" need to be invoked in order to be accelerated, but I couldn't find any.

Are BC's AES engines completely software implementations? If so, that's not so good given that many modern MCUs/CPUs provide AES modules - correct? A similar question was asked about [5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045520/aes-acceleration-for-java?rq=1), but the situation was somewhat different as hardware acceleration was not prevalent.

Comment: There are instructions in the CPU that are special made for AES.  One of them, for example, does a single round of AES.  As this round function is all in hardware, it is very fast.  As for Bouncy Castle's library, I don't know.  I imagine the only way to access those instructions is to write the assembly by hand.  It seems unlikely a compiler would recognize AES when it sees it and shift it to those special CPU instructions in the compiled code.  On the other hand, maybe there is a special function in C++ that expressly compiles to those instructions.  But if BC did any of this, I don't know

Comment: Bouncycastle is pure Java, and thus will not take advantage of AES hardware. Actually, a good Java JIT compiler could in principle figure this out, but in reality no Java compiler will ever be that smart.

Comment: According to http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/AES-NI-support-td3305120.html it is not supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Bouncy Castle it is not supported and will not be supported:
https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/221

Answer (score 1):

LTS versions of BouncyCastle now support AES-NI on Linux.

From https://www.bouncycastle.org/lts-java/

> One additional feature of this release is that it includes JNI support for Intel AES, DRBG/RNG, and SHA2 as well as ARM AES and SHA2. Please note that at the moment JNI support is only available on Linux.

See also https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/1396